# How to update component with ajax when selecting a p:selectOneRadio?

Tags: ajax, jsf

I'm trying to use ajax to update a component in my jsf page when selecting a radio button.
The managed bean is the following:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class TestMB {
   ArrayList<String> domande;
   String[] risposte = new String[3];

   public TestMB() {
       domande = new ArrayList<String>();
       domande.add("Domanda1");
       domande.add("Domanda2");
       domande.add("Domanda3");
   }

   public ArrayList<String> getDomande() {
       return domande;
   }

   public void setDomande(ArrayList<String> domande) {
       this.domande = domande;
   }

   public String[] getRisposte() {
       return risposte;
   }

   public void setRisposte(String[] risposte) {
       this.risposte = risposte;
   }

   public void asserta() {
       System.out.println(risposte[0]);
   }
}
```

The JSF page is this one:

```
<h:form id="label">
  <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid" styleClass="showcase-text-align-center">
    <p:repeat var="domanda" value="#{testMB.domande}" varStatus="status">
      <h1>#{domanda}</h1>
      <p:selectOneRadio value="#{testMB.risposte[status.index]}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3"></f:selectItem>
      </p:selectOneRadio>
    </p:repeat>

  </p:panelGrid>
  <p:outputLabel value="#{testMB.risposte[0]}"></p:outputLabel>

  <p:commandButton update="label" value="Si" />
</h:form>>
```

I would like to update the form when I change option in the  tag.
If I press the commandButton everything is ok but how to implement the same behavior in the radio button selection?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You obiously know about ajax, why is there no ajax in the `p:selectoneradio`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `<p:ajax>` component. Try something like this:

```
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{testMB.risposte[status.index]}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3"></f:selectItem>
    <p:ajax update="label" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```